# Script launch only on click event

Tags: javascript

Hello i'm trying to track a onclick event from my add to cart button, so i have a script in

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var button = document.getElementById('addToCartButton');
        button.addEventListener(
            'click',
            function () {
                fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
                    content_name: 'Really Fast Running Shoes',
                    content_category: 'Apparel & Accessories > Shoes',
                    content_ids: ['1234'],
                    content_type: 'product',
                    value: 4.99,
                    currency: 'USD'
                });
            },
            false
        );
    </script>
</head>

<button
                id="addToCartButton"
                class="mt-5 w-full   rounded-xl bg-vert p-2 py-3.5 font-bold text-white"
                >ADD TO CART
            </button>
```

The problem is : when i refresh the website, the event is working without click on button
If someone can help me, thanks

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the event is working. I think you get confused between the errors, but don't worry.

The thing is that the **script tag** should be in the **body** specially in the bottom of the **body** and not in the **head** so all the tags will be first loaded than can JavaScript get the button for you but how are doing it is that you prepare your script before the **HTML tags** are being loaded, so JavaScript can't find them.

```
<body>
  <button id="addToCartButton" class="mt-5 w-full   rounded-xl bg-vert p-2 py-3.5 font-bold text-white">ADD TO CART</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById('addToCartButton');
    button.addEventListener(
      'click',
      function () {
        fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
          content_name: 'Really Fast Running Shoes',
          content_category: 'Apparel & Accessories > Shoes',
          content_ids: ['1234'],
          content_type: 'product',
          value: 4.99,
          currency: 'USD'
        });
      },
      false
    );
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I made it, but the event is working without click on button

Comment: Is that your full script?